# In the example code, the 'define' macro is used in C++ to define classes, and the use of pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, stl

https://github.com/Alinshans/MyTinySTL
In the test.h of this link, I have two doubts.

1. I can't seem to find the definition of TestCase::Run
2. Can't understand the meaning of the following code

```
#define TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name) \
    testcase_name##_TEST


#define MYTINYSTL_TEST_(testcase_name)                        \
class TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name) : public TestCase {        \
public:                                                       \
    TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name)(const char* case_name)       \
        : TestCase(case_name) {};                             \
    virtual void Run();                                       \
private:                                                      \
    static TestCase* const testcase_;                         \
};                                                            \
                                                              \
TestCase* const TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name)                  \
    ::testcase_ = UnitTest::GetInstance()->RegisterTestCase(  \
        new TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name)(#testcase_name));    \
void TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name)::Run()
```

Comment: If anyone knows the answer, this will help me a lot, thanks

Comment: I see that in the test.h file, there is a pure virtual function with virtual void Run()=0 in the TestCase class, but I can't find its definition.These should be source code, not cmake generated stuff.@drescherjm

Comment: `TestCase::Run` is a pure virtual member function of `TestCase`. It's pure virtual, so it has no definition. You can find out what the macros become by expanding them.

Comment: Thank you, I found it, it uses the TEST macro to define the subclass virtual function. I want to ask one more question. In line 98 of test.h testcase->Run();, the Run function of testcase is a pure virtual function of the parent class, why does it directly call the pure virtual function of the parent class.@molbdnilo

Comment: It doesn't do that. Don't you know how polymorphism and virtual functions work?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see definition of `TestCase::Run`, because you are supposed to provide one yourself.

Notice, how macro definition ends with `void TESTCASE_NAME(testcase_name)::Run()`. This is not a valid C++ statement. You are expected to follow up with function body, which will be the body of `Run` method definition:

```
MYTINYSTL_TEST_(some_unique_name_you_came_with)
{
    // Some code for testing
    // 
}
```

*MYTINYSTL_TEST_* macro will generate a unique subclass of `TestCase`, register it (during static member creation) with some testing framework and that framework will later run body you provided.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 1.The TestCase::Run here is a pure virtual function. The pure virtual function should be implemented in the subclass, so that if it is not defined, it will not compile and report an error? 2.In addition, in line 98, `testcase->Run();`, the Run function of TestCase has been called. Can you call a function that has not yet been defined?@Revolver_Ocelot

Comment: @gordon_zheng `MYTINYSTL_TEST_` macro will create a subclass of TestCase and it ends with definition of that subclass Run method (which you are supposed to provide body to).

Comment: Thanks,I see, I have one more question. In line 98 of test.h `testcase->Run();`, the Run function of testcase is a pure virtual function of the parent class, why does it directly call the pure virtual function of the parent class

Comment: @gordon_zheng it doesn't call function of parent class, it calls overriding function of one of its children. That the whole point of virtual fuctions.

Comment: I imitated a piece of code, but the compiler reported a segfault. I want it to run the fun function that subclasses Derived, but I don't know where is the error@Revolver_Ocelot

Comment: `#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
  
class Base
{
   int x;
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
    int getX() { return x; }
};
  
class Derived: public Base
{
    int y;
public:
    void fun() { cout << "fun() called"; }
};

class UnitTest
{
public:
  static UnitTest* GetInstance();
  void Run();

public:

protected:
  Base* b;  
};

UnitTest* UnitTest::GetInstance()
{
  static UnitTest instance;
  return &instance;
}
void UnitTest::Run()
{
    b->fun();
}

int main(void)
{
    UnitTest::GetInstance()->Run();
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @gordon_zheng You never assign anything to `Base* b;` you need to create Derived object and assign pointer to it to Base pointer.

Comment: You are amazing！ I changed `Base* b;` to `Base* b = new Derived`; and it works successfully now. I also understand the operation mechanism of test.h, thank you!